# Получение данных с открытой вкладки браузера через python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите модуль для python3 которым можно получить информацию с уже открытой страници браузера.

Comment: Используйте модуль `selenium`.

Comment: Если ты хочешь с html страниц, то import pandas тебе поможет

Comment: А как pandas поможет? Методом, что из html страниц вытаскивает таблицы (<table>)? Так маловероятно, что автору именно это нужно :) а так, есть: urlopen, requests, `...`

Comment: @gil9red, через requests приходится не получилось, да почитал доки по urlopen, там тоже не то. Надо именно во вкладке которую я открыл, а не как selenium который открывает свою копию браузера. На сайте стоит защита от автоматических систем, а заморачиваться с ее обходом нет знаний и опыта.

Comment: @SacredSacred, интересно, можно ли selenium'ом подключиться к текущему браузеру... кст, встречал модуль https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/browsercookie (не играл с ним), который вытаскивает куки из браузера, позволяя, например, urlopen ходить с ними. Т.е. можно авторизоваться на сайте через браузер и ходить к нему с куками браузера через скрипт

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо. Это очень интересный момент, попробую этот вариант